# I am getting this error.I am not able to resolve this

Tags: python

```py
import pyramid
print(pyramid.__version__)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 import pyramid
>   ----> 2 print(pyramid.**version**)

AttributeError: module 'pyramid' has no attribute '**version**'

Comment: what's the actual question ?

Comment: You seem to be a beginner so I would suggest you go through some `python` [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) before you tackle writing a web framework in Pyramid. After that you can try [Quick Tutorial for Pyramid](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html). If you only need the answer to your question, `print(pyramid.__version__)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

That module does not have a function to get the version directly.

```
import pyramid
dir(pyramid)
```

Result:

```
['__builtins__','__cached__','__doc__','__file__','__loader__','__name__',
'__package__','__path__','__spec__']
```

Instead, run below if you are using mac or if you are using Windows, use findstr:

```
pip list | grep pyramid

Result:
pyramid  1.10.4
```

If you are using ipython notebook, add !

```
! pip list | grep pyramid
pyramid   1.10.4
```